# How to evaluate current in a circuit involving short circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to solve this homework question:

[image]

I got the short circuit in the middle by removing a voltage source. The problem is to find the current flowing through R6.

What I tried:

- Applying Star-Delta transformation on R3, R4 and R5 however it did not lead me anywhere.
- I also cannot seem to be able to apply mesh analysis as no voltages are supplied to me.
- I cannot convert the current source to a voltage source as there is no resistance in parallel with it.

Can someone please give me a hint as to how I should reduce this circuit?

Edit: Circuit after removing the short-circuited element R2:

Thanks to @Transistor and @MCG: I now was able to apply star-delta

[image]

Thanks to @Transistor and @MCG: I now was able to apply star-delta transformation which reduced the circuit to this:

[image]

I was able to solve this using current division.

P.S. The answer supplied by LTspice is 6 A for R6.

Comment: Hint #1: One component is short-circuited so it can be removed. Redraw and post the modified circuit at the end of your question.

Comment: @Transistor Hi! I tried doing that, but the simulation answer changed from 6A to 5A in both LTspice and CircuitLabs, so I thought that was an incorrect operation. Is it actually valid?

Comment: You tried doing what? What component did you remove?

Comment: I'm sorry, you meant removing the 15ohm resistor. I misunderstood.

Comment: There are four 15 Ω resistors. Use the component numbers to be clear.

Comment: When you say the 15 ohm resistor..... there are a few of them. Re-draw the circuit logically, make it easier, then remove the short circuited one.

Comment: In 40 years as an EE I have never needed to do anything like this calculation. Just in case you wanted to know...

Answer (score 3):

You've worked it out on your own. Congratulations. Here's how I would have approached it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT4F0x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The original. Note that R2 is short-circuited. It can be removed.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMw0Yx.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Note that R3 and R4 are in parallel.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsdFBN.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Now we can add the series resistances.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8J1Rw.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. This is as far as we need to go.*

You can apply your current division here.